# Paw Installation Error

Tags: installation

I need to install PAW (Physics Analysis Workstation) on my system for some analysis. I am working on a Macintosh system (Sierra), I tried installing it through Homebrew : brew cask install paw . The installation was successful, but when I run the script which calls for using paw to plot some data, I get the following error:

sh:paw: command not found.

Any suggestions how to fix this?